How is the real line a geodesic in the complex upper half-plane?
I'm in the middle of trying to prove that all hyperbolic isometries are Möbius transformations in the upper half-plane and I keep seeing people mention looking at points on the real line and references to how the real line is a special geodesic in the upper half-plane model, but if we define the plane as {$z\in\mathbb{C}|$Im$(z)>0$}, then how would points on the real line even be considered elements of this set when by definition they are the points in $\mathbb{C}$ where Im$(z)=0$? What am I missing here?
Edit: thanks to a comment I'm adding specifics. I'm seeing people talk about looking at how hyperbolic isometries act on the real line, the complex line, and points at infinity, and then comparing them with the general form of Möbius transformations as part of the larger proof to show that all hyperbolic isometries in the complex upper half-plane are in fact Möbius transformations. They suggest that points along the real line are preserved under hyperbolic transformations, kind of because the real line is invariant under hyperbolic isometries? They state this is a Möbius transformation of the form $f(z)=Re(z)$. Which then leads to my confusion because how would this transformation be in the complex upper half-plane? Shouldn't we be talking about $f(z)=Re(z)+ig(Im(z))$ where $g(Im(z))>0$? I'm sure there's some key information/understanding about Möbius transformations I must be missing here.

You are right, the real line is disjoint from the upper half plane model. I would suggest explicitly editing your post to include exact examples of what you "keep seeing people mention"; perhaps there is some easily corrected misunderstanding.

@LeeMosher thank you! I've added some specifics to the OP.

I think all that is going on in your post is some carelessness and confusion regarding domains and ranges, and a consequent confusion about the difference between "Möbius transformations" and "hyperbolic isometries".
To make things clear, let me write out the proper expression for the Möbius transformations that are relevant to this problem, namely those functions
$$f : \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\} \to \mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}
$$
which are given by formulas of the form
$$f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d} \quad a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R, \quad ad-bc=1
$$
When the upper half plane $\mathbb H = \{x+iy \mid y>0\}$ is equipped with the Riemannian metric $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$, then it is true that if $Im(z) > 0$ then $Im(f(z))>0$, in other words
$$z \in \mathbb H \implies f(z) \in \mathbb H
$$
and you get a restricted function $f : \mathbb H \to \mathbb H$, and this restricted function is a "hyperbolic isometry".
It is also true that if we identify $\mathbb R = \{x+0i\} \subset \mathbb C$ then
$$z \in \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\} \implies f(z) \in \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}
$$
In other words, if $Im(z)=0$ or $z=\infty$, then $Im(f(z))=0$ or $f(z)=\infty$. But you should not refer to the restricted function $f : \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\} \to \mathbb R \cup\{\infty\}$ using the words "hyperbolic isometry". And I would not say that points along the real line are "preserved by the hyperbolic isometry" $f : \mathbb H \to \mathbb H$.
I would suggest instead that you simply be very very careful to distinguish between three different functions. These functions may all have the same formula, but their domains and ranges make them different functions: the Möbius transformation $f$ defined on the whole set $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$; the hyperbolic isometry $f$ defined on the restricted subset $\mathbb H$; and the function $f$ defined on the restricted subset $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$. Mayyyyybe you could refer to that last function as something like the "values at infinity of the hyperbolic isometry", but I suggest holding off on that kind of language until you understand better what is going on.
